# How do I get the Bootstrap DateTimePicker to display the correct year?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

One of the features of a website that I maintain is creating/updating an upcoming event. Users need to be able to select the date and time of the event, but I've discovered that if the date selected is during the last week of the year, and there are days in that week that are in the next year, then the year is automatically set to the next year.

For example, if Dec. 29, 2019 is selected, then the date that is inserted into the database is Dec. 29, 2020.
Further, if I open a module with the event data in it, it will display the date as being Dec. 29, 2021, even though the database has it recorded as being in 2020.

Since Dec. 28, 2019 is Saturday and isn't in the same week as days in 2020, it will be inserted into the database as Dec. 28, 2019.

Here's some of the ColdFusion code for the event module:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <cfdump var="#event.event_date_time#" expand="yes"></cfdump>
    <label>Event Date and Time:</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='updateEventDateTime'>
        <input required type='text' name="updateEventDateTime" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Select event date and time" 
               value="#DateTimeFormat(event.event_date_time,'MM/dd/YYYY H:nn tt')#"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <cfdump var="#event.event_date_time#" expand="yes"></cfdump>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript for the DateTimePicker:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        // Create the Bootstrap Datetimepicker for the event
        // date and time
        $('#updateEventDateTime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY H:mm A',
            sideBySide: true
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here's a screenshot of what the above ColdFusion code outputs:

Wrong Year in DateTime:

[image]

Any ideas of what I should do to fix this? It hasn't been an issue in the past 2 years that I've maintained this site, and while it obviously isn't an issue for users now, it will be in November/December and I'd rather fix it now.

EDIT: There are two main operations that both need fixing. Users need to be able to add an event and update an event. The ColdFusion code above is in the updateEvent module, and part of the code for the addEvent module is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Event Date and Time:</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='addEventDateTime'>
        <input required type='text' name="addEventDateTime" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Select event date and time" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code in this module contains this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // Create the Bootstrap Datetimepicker for the event
    // date and time
    $('#addEventDateTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY H:mm A',
        sideBySide: true
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to the joys of Java's SimpleDateFormat and the difference between Year (y) and WeekYear (Y). Just use a lowercase y in your mask.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Also note that your masks in Javascript may be different. And not all ColdFusion functions use Java SimpleDateFormat, so the mask case may not matter. Plus, I believe in CF2016 or CF2018, the masks for those functions no longer look at case. I wrote about this a bit before. When I get home I'll find the page that steps through a lot of examples and uses that return unexpected results.

Comment: When I set the mask in the javascript to "yyyy" instead of "YYYY", it tries to insert the value "yyyy" as the year, rather than using it as a mask.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of ColdFusion we're running but I'll check and get back to you

Comment: @SlowCuber17 - I think Shawn meant use "yyyy" in the ColdFusion code, i.e. `DateTimeFormat` (not JS). Sounds like you're using CF11.

Comment: I checked, and I am running CF11.

Comment: Setting the mask to "yyyy" in ColdFusion on the updateEvent module partially works. It will display the correct date in the module, but when I try to set it to the correct date, even though it displays the correct date, it will still increment the year when I save the changes and push the data to the database.

Comment: If the javascript component sends the correct date string to CF (for saving), then it sounds like there's another issue in the CF responsible for saving the value to the database. Could you post that code?

Comment: @Shawn - Since that turned out to be the issue, you should post an official answer (later).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about multiple different things here: you're working with the Javascript in your Bootstrap template, your ColdFusion variables, and your database. All 3 can affect the ultimate date that you see, and what you see isn't a date object (like the database ultimately should want), but a string representation of a date object.

When you look at a date, it probably looks like `March 27, 2019 12:00:00 pm` or `03/27/2019 12:00:00 pm` or `27/03/2019 12:00:00.000` or something like that. When a database or a programming language sees that string as a date object, it looks like `123465789.123465798`, which is usually a specific value of seconds since whatever epoch your system component uses. *`Epoch` is a whole different topic altogether.*

Since a long decimal isn't really human-readable as a date, your language has to perform masking to convert back and forth between the two representations.

You want to keep in mind which piece of your code you're using to do the masking. Usually, masking is for display, but you may also need it to transform a string into a date-readable object on your database before it will insert it. So, you'll want to check that your Javascript isn't doing anything with the value in your form, that your ColdFusion isn't doing anything with that Javascript string, and that your database isn't further changing that ColdFusion string.

I'm not sure what Bootstrap's `datapicker` uses to interpret date strings or if it's ultimately sending an odd string to your ColdFusion, but I do know that CF11 uses different masking depending on the function you're using. `DateFormat()` doesn't care what case you use, but `DateTimeFormat()` does. It relies on the masking definition of its underlying Java `SimpleDateFormat`, which interprets `y` and `Y` as different masks meaning different things.

The big pain is that, as you saw, it will only be visible a few days at the end of a year, since a year is never made up of exactly 52 weeks. So we have another type of date called a `WeekYear`, or `Y` in `SimpleDateFormat` masking. It's essentially what Year it is based on the Week (`W` or `w`). So for just a few days at the beginning and end of a year, the Calendar Year won't equal the Week Year. For the other 358 or so days of a year, they'll be the same. And since New Years and New Years Eve are often non-working holidays, it's *VERY EASY* to overlook. So, essentially, your code hasn't been working correctly the last couple of years; you just haven't had cause to notice. Fun, right?

For a simple example, see: https://trycf.com/gist/5cb651559e28e5cbdecdb57b959c3c18/acf11?theme=monokai

And if you notice, both `dateFormat()` and `timeFormat()` will mask beyond what they're "technically" supposed to do. You can get `timeFormat()` to apply a mask to the `date` part of a string, too. They *shouldn't* work that way.

As I have said in multiple places, date handling (in almost any language) is a pet peeve of mine. It's a topic that will make you want to pull your hair out. And possibly the hair of anyone sitting next to you. And *DEFINITELY* the hair of whoever wrote the date handling code that you're debugging. It is completely a Code-rage-inducing topic.

Anyway, if you want to look at some other examples, I've written about it a couple of times before, and probably will do so again. Thanks for drawing me back into this rabbit hole of sheer madness.

https://codefumonkey.blogspot.com/2016/02/date-masking-inconsistency.html
https://codefumonkey.blogspot.com/2016/10/more-date-masking.html

**NOTE:** More recent versions of CF have changed the behavior of the masking in some of the date functions. They aren't case-sensitive in CF2018, so it doesn't matter if you use `yyyy` or `YYYY`. But do yourself a favor and use `yyyy` since you know that CF is still built upon Java. However, there are some other frameworks that expect `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`, so it's still very important to remember what language it is that you are using to apply the mask. And if you don't need to see the date value and can continue to work with a date object, leave it that way instead of making it a readable string.

Comment: In addition - 1) Be sure to use cfqueryparam on all query parameters. Otherwise, it leaves the query open to sql injection. 2) When using date values in a query, don't rely on Date/TimeFormat functions. A) If the input isn't a date object, the function uses "guesswork" to convert it into one (which CF often gets wrong) and B) The function returns a string, which is ambiguous. Instead, take a look at parseDateTime(), which supports masks as of CF11+, and returns a date object suitable for use in db query.

Comment: @Ageax True. To be honest, you shouldn't be sending a string into a query for a date anyway if the database is looking for a date object. And if the db stores the date as a varchar(), there are other issues. :-)   By the time it gets to the database, it should already be a date object. Also note that `ParseDateTime` uses US Locale Format. so our non-US friends might want to use `LSParseDateTime`.

Comment: And there's also `createODBCDateTime()` if you already have a CF date object.

Comment: Totally agreed on dates. Passing date strings into a db query just creates a second chance for them to be mangled.. "Been there, done that, wouldn't reccommend it" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. When the "Save" button is pressed, the data is put into a struct which is passed into the following function:

```
<cffunction name="addEvent" access="public" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="eventStruct" type="struct" required="yes">
<!--- Verify the structure is formated correctly --->

<!--- Checks if all the required elements of the struct are there --->

<!--- Verify the date object is correct --->
<cfif NOT isDate(ARGUMENTS.eventStruct.eventDateTime)>
    <cfset errorCode = "INVALID_VARIABLE_TYPE">
    <cflog file="chapter-reports" type="error" 
        text="#errorCode#: variable must be a coldfusion date object">
    <cfreturn errorCode />
</cfif>
<!--- Format the date --->
<cfset ARGUMENTS.eventStruct.eventDateTime = DateTimeFormat(ARGUMENTS.eventStruct.eventDateTime,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss")>
<!--- Insert the event into the table --->
<cftry>
    <cfquery datasource="#VARIABLES.datasource#" name="insertEvent" result="newEvent">
        INSERT INTO #VARIABLES.tablePrefix#events
        (/*column names*/,event_date_time,/*more column names*/)
        VALUES(
            /*data*/,
            '#ARGUMENTS.eventStruct.eventDateTime#',
            /*more data*/
        )
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Send an error message if there is a database error --->

</cftry>
<cfreturn newEvent.generated_key />
```

Originally, it would format the date with "YYYY", but after changing it to "yyyy", it works as intended.

Comment: Glad things are working. A few tips 1) *Always* use cfqueryparam on client supplied values to protect your database against sql injection 2) Don't use `DateTimeFormat()`. It's the wrong function. It's designed to display things in a user friendly way on the client side. To convert a date string *into* a date object, using a specific mask, use [`ParseDateTime`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html).